# Is it possible to pan the map in QGIS composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pan

I am relatively new to the composer feature of QGIS, and often have difficulty getting the map centred exactly where I want it. In particular the area of interest often moves when I set the scale.

Is it possible to pan or otherwise centre a plot that is easier than adjusting the extents manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I interpret your issue correctly, you are looking for the **move item content** tool which is the rightmost tool button you can see in the toolbar @Joseph posted.

Location of the **move item content** tool in QGIS 3:
[image: Screenshot of QGIS 3]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the pan function:

[image]